# FindFirstChangeNotification fires multiple times

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, events, wait

I have a simple application which spawns two threads and assigns one with a task of processing some file and saving the result to another one, while the other thread retrieves information about it's parent process.
I'm using some manual reset events and a `FindFirstChangeNotification` function. The primary thread enters an infinite loop, inside calling `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

Here's the snippet:

```c
while(TRUE){
waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(4, eventObjectHandles, FALSE, 5000, FALSE);
    switch(waitResult){
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
            _tprintf(_T("\nThread with ID: %d has finished processing the poem.\n"), threadIds[0]);
            _tprintf(_T("Output file path: %s\n"), thread_xyz_param.outputPath);
            ResetEvent(eventObjectHandles[0])
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            ResetEvent(eventObjectHandles[1]);
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
            _tprintf(_T("Error in thread with ID: %d!\n"), threadIds[0]);
            ResetEvent(eventObjectHandles[2]);
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 3:
            _tprintf(_T("Error in thread with ID: %d!\n"), threadIds[1]);
            ResetEvent(eventObjectHandles[3]);
            break;
    }

    GetExitCodeThread(threadHandles[0], &firstThreadStatus);
    GetExitCodeThread(threadHandles[1], &secondThreadStatus);

    if((firstThreadStatus != STILL_ACTIVE) && (secondThreadStatus != STILL_ACTIVE)){
        break;
    }
}
```

Problem is that the the `FindFirstChangeNotification` function is signalling multiple times, even though I write to the output file only once.
Is it a good idea to call `FindCloseChangeNotification` instead of `ResetEvent`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handle returned by `FindFirstChangeNotification` cannot be passed to `ResetEvent`. If you want to wait for another event, use `FindNextChangeNotification`. If you are finished with it, then use `FindCloseChangeNotification`.

This is implied by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx): "If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to a find change notification object." It returns a handle to a find change notification object, not an event. Therefore, it is an invalid parameter to `ResetEvent`.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that. Thank you!